# Code way for creating a Authorization Code JWT token

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, oauth-2.0, api-authorization

I am looking for a way to create a JWT that can I obtain using Postman Grant Type "Authorization Code", using an existing Callback URL (that I can't modify / localhost is not permited).

I would like to create a NodeJS / Go small application that could mymic the Postman way of authorizing this flow.

AFAIK, the only way would be to run the redirect url in a window that is controlled by the code, and extracting the authorization code after login in order to get the correct token.

Can't seems to to make this code extraction after the login page...

If someone could point me to the right way :)

Will add a small JS code (using puppeteer to mimic Postman browser) I've been playing with, that is failing since the `"Invalid authorization code: 2j3ZN75HXNz4Uw4JsS3n8xhQpzVfa73Y"`, although this code is definitely the correct one.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = "URL"

const ENV = {}
const account = {
    username: "USERNAME", password: "PASSWORD"
}

// Sending a POST request with puppeteer, since I would like to do it from the browser instance itself, not axios.
async function gotoExtended(page, request) {
    const { url, method, headers, postData } = request;
    const cookies = await page.cookies()
    console.log(cookies)

    if (method !== 'GET' || postData || headers) {
        let wasCalled = false;
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);
        const interceptRequestHandler = async (request) => {
            try {
                if (wasCalled) {
                    return await request.continue();
                }

                wasCalled = true;
                const requestParams = {};

                if (method !== 'GET') requestParams.method = method;
                if (postData) requestParams.postData = postData;
                if (headers) requestParams.headers = headers;
                await request.continue(requestParams);
                await page.setRequestInterception(false);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error while request interception', { error });
            }
        };

        await page.on('request', interceptRequestHandler);
    }

    return page.goto(url);
}


async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    let code;

    page.on('response', response => {
        const status = response.status()
        if ((status >= 300) && (status <= 399)) {
            console.log('Redirect from', response.url(), 'to', response.headers()['location'])
            if (response.url().includes('callback?code=')) {
                let str = response.url();
                code = str.split('callback?code=')[1];
                console.log(code)
            }
        }
    })

    await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 720});
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'}); // wait until page load
    await page.type('#j_username', account.username);
    await page.type('#j_password', account.password);
    // click and wait for navigation
    await Promise.all([page.click('#logOnFormSubmit'), page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'}),]);

    const options = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": "CORRECT - Base64 of ClientId:ClientSecret",
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
        }
    }

    const data = `grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${ENV.redirectUri}&${ENV.clientId}`

    await gotoExtended(page, { url: ENV.authURL, method: 'POST', postData: data, headers: options.headers });

    console.log(await page.content());

    await browser.close();
}

main().then(() => console.log("End"));
```

Thanks

#### EDIT

Code is indeed working, so this was what I was thinking about. Just needed some tweaking.

Comment: If you need to automate a browser to go through the part of an OpenID Connect flow including when the user logs in, one option for doing the automation is Selenium. I hope this is for testing though, or else it will be brittle and break if the page you are logging into is ever updated (any browser automation would run into this problem IMO).

Answer (score 0):

After validating the code - adding the updated code for future self.

```
require('dotenv').config()
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirectUri = process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
  redirectUriEncoded = encodeURIComponent(redirectUri),
  authenticationUrl = process.env.AUTHENTICATION_URL,
  url = `${authenticationUrl}/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${encodeURIComponent(
    clientId
  )}&redirect_uri=${redirectUriEncoded}`,
  username = process.env.USERNAME,
  password = process.env.PASSWORD;

async function gotoExtended(page, request) {
  const { url, method, headers, postData } = request;

  if (method !== "GET" || postData || headers) {
    let wasCalled = false;
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    const interceptRequestHandler = async (request) => {
      try {
        if (wasCalled) {
          return await request.continue();
        }

        wasCalled = true;
        const requestParams = {};

        if (method !== "GET") {
          requestParams.method = method;
        }
        if (postData) {
          requestParams.postData = postData;
        }
        if (headers) {
          requestParams.headers = headers;
        }
        await request.continue(requestParams);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error while request interception", { error });
      }
    };

    await page.on("request", interceptRequestHandler);
  }

  return page.goto(url);
}

async function main() {
  console.log("***Start***");
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  let code;

  page.on("response", (response) => {
    const status = response.status();
    if (status >= 300 && status <= 399) {
      if (response.headers()["location"].includes("callback?code=")) {
        let str = response.headers()["location"];
        code = str.split("callback?code=")[1];
      }
    }
  });

  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" }); // wait until page load
  await page.type("#j_username", username);
  await page.type("#j_password", password);

  await Promise.all([
    page.click("#logOnFormSubmit"),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" }),
  ]);

  const encodedBase64Authorization = Buffer.from(
    `${clientId}:${clientSecret}`
  ).toString("base64");

  const options = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Authorization: `Basic ${encodedBase64Authorization}`,
      Accept: "*/*",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    },
  };

  const data = `grant_type=authorization_code&code=${code}&redirect_uri=${redirectUriEncoded}&client_id=${clientId}`;

  await gotoExtended(page, {
    url: `${authenticationUrl}/oauth/token`,
    method: "POST",
    postData: data,
    headers: options.headers,
  });

  const { access_token } = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return JSON.parse(document.querySelector("body").innerText);
  });

  console.log(access_token);

  await browser.close();
}

main().then(() => console.log("***End***"));
```